# navbar brand not styling and navbar has no background color just transparent

Tags: background, bootstrap-4, navbar

My navbar won't play ball. It's almost there but I have two problems which I can't seem to resolve.

1) When you scroll the page the navbar is transparent. I added some padding to the top for spacing but I can't see why it's transparent. There are no opacity settings in my CSS!

2) I've got my logo aligned to the right with navbar-brand but no matter what I do with the CSS I can't seem to change the text color, size or type.

3) I'm also struggling to make the background image fill the whole page. I've tried all sorts to make it fit but it won't.

Can anyone help with my problems? I've temporarily hosted the index page as I have a feeling something in the rest of my css is messing up my navbar!

Here is the link...
http://www.wisbechinlinespeed.co.uk/index-new.htm

I've googled the problems and tried most suggestions, but nothing seems to be working.

```
.menu-area{background: #F9F3DB; }

.dropdown-menu{padding:0;margin:0;border:0 solid transition!important;border:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);border-radius:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none!important;box-shadow:none!important}

.mainmenu a,   .navbar-default
.navbar-nav > li > a, 
.mainmenu ul li a , 
.navbar-expand-lg     .navbar-nav .nav-link{color:#6D6C6B;font-size:16px;text-transform:capitalize;padding:10px 10px;font-family:'calibri',sans-serif;display: block !important;}


/*==========WISS logo==========*/
 .navbar-default 
 .navbar-brand .navbar-text {
color:#6D6C6B;}
/*==========active page properties==========*/
.mainmenu 
.active a,
.mainmenu 
.active a:focus,
.mainmenu 
.active a:hover,
.mainmenu li a:hover,
.mainmenu li a:focus ,
.navbar-default 
.navbar-nav>.show>a, 
.navbar-default 
.navbar-nav>.show>a:focus, 
.navbar-default 
.navbar-nav>.show>a:hover{background: #6D6C6B; color: #F9F3DB; outline: 0;}


/*==========Sub Menu=v==========*/

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul > li:hover > a{background: #6D6C6B;color: #F9F3DB; }

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul ul > li:hover > a, 
.navbar-default 
.navbar-nav 
.show 

.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, 
.navbar-default 
.navbar-nav 

.show 
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{background: #6D6C6B;}

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul ul ul > li:hover > a{background: #6D6C6B;}


.mainmenu .collapse ul ul, 
.mainmenu .collapse ul ul
.dropdown-menu{background:#d9d9d8;}

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul ul ul, 
.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul
.dropdown-menu{background:#d9d9d8}

.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul ul, 
.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul ul
.dropdown-menu{background:#d9d9d8}



/******************************Drop-down menu work on hover**********************************/

.mainmenu{background: none;border: 0 solid;margin: 0;padding: 0;min-height:20px;width: 100%;}


@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul li:hover> ul{display:block}

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul ul{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;min-width:250px;display:none}

/*******/

.mainmenu 
.collapse ul ul li{position:relative}
.mainmenu .collapse ul ul li:hover> ul{display:block}

.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:100%;min-width:250px;display:none}

/*******/

.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul li{position:relative}

.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul li:hover ul{display:block}

.mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul ul{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100%;min-width:250px;display:none;z-index:1}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu 
.dropdown-menu > li > a{padding:16px 15px 16px 35px}

.navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu 
.dropdown-menu 
.dropdown-menu > li > a{padding:16px 15px 16px 45px}
}

<!------ nav bar ---------->



<div id="menu_area" class="menu-area">

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top mainmenu">
 <a class="navbar-brand order-md-last" href="#">WISBECH INLINE SPEED</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


<li class="active"><a href="index.htm">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

<li><a href="home.htm">News</a></li>


<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Club Information</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">


<li><a href="about.htm">About Us</a></li>

<li><a href="join.htm">Join Our Club</a></li>

<li><a href="stats.htm">Club Statistics</a></li>

<li><a href="calendar.htm">Calendar</a></li>

<li><a href="results.htm">Results</a></li>

<li><a href="track.htm">Track Info</a></li>

<li><a href="docs.htm">Official Documents</a></li>

<li><a href="sponsorship.htm">Sponsorship</a></li>

<li><a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a></li>

<li><a href="links.htm">Links</a></li>

</ul>   

<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Meet The Team</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">


<li><a href="team.htm">The Team</a></li>

<li><a href="coaches.htm">The Coaches</a></li>

<li><a href="committee.htm">The Committee</a></li>
 </ul>

<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Training Tips</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">


<li><a href="nutrition.htm">Nutrition</a></li>

<li><a href="technique.htm">Technique</a></li>

<li><a href="injuries.htm">Preventing Injuries</a></li>

<li><a href="maintenance.htm">Maintenance</a></li>

<li><a href="equipment.htm">Equipment</a></li>
</ul>

<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Galleries</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">


<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photos</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

<li><a href="#">2018</a></li>

<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>

<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>


</ul>



<li><a href="#">Team Photos</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>


<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Media</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

<li><a href="#">Press Reports</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
  </ul>


<li class="dropdown">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Archives</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

<li><a href="#">1980's and 90's</a></li>

<li><a href="#">2000's</a></li>

</ul>

</li>

</ul>

</li>

</ul>

</li>

</ul>

</div>

</nav>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<!------ end new nav bar ---------->
```

1) Transparent navbar but I want it to be #F9F3DB
2) navbar brand CSS doesn't change the text type, I want to change the color, font type and size
3) Background image of the entire page doesn't fill the page. I would like it to fit right to the bottom.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the coding for the background image problem.

Comment: CSS: /* background image*/
.bg-image {height: 100%; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover;}
.img1 { background-image: url("backgrounds/001.jpg"); }

Comment: HTML: 
<div class="bg-image img1">

Answer (score 0):

1) For the first problem the solution is to remove the div container, row container and menu-area. I don't know if they are needed but in many bootstrap examples there is just nav tag. example:

```
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<nav>
    <div>
        <img>
        <div>
            <a><!--Here put the logo image or text--></a>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>First</a></li>
            <li><a>Second</a></li>
            <li><a>.....</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Examples are here [Bootstrap Navbar Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Done this, just set the background in the .mainmenu class:

```
.mainmenu {
background: none;
border: 0 solid;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-height: 20px;
width: 100%;
background: #f9f3db; /*---background set---*/
}
```

2) For this the solution is easy because you use navbar-dark class that has color: white that takes over from your css rules. So you can do two things.Or remove that class if it is useless for you, or use !important after css rules. example:

```
.mainmenu a{
 color: #fff !important; 
}
```

3) Should be this the solution:

```
background-position: right bottom;
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your reply. None of your suggestions helped I'm afraid. The only thing that did work is changing.navbar-dark which changed my logo from white, but I'm still unable to change the font for just the logo.

Comment: My .navbar-brand css is being over-ridden by something else in my css I think and I can't change the font type or size.  Your css suggestion for this changes the text for the whole navbar but I just want to change the logo. The .background-position suggestion didn't work at all and neither did your answer for my first question regarding the background of the nav bar. Could there be something which is over-riding all my css? I'm confused becuase in theory your suggestions and the changes I've already made aren't working.

Comment: Quick update on problem 3) I changed my body css to this

Comment: body { height:100%; padding-top:40px; font-size: 15px; background-color: #F9F3DB;   background-image: url("backgrounds/001.jpg");   background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; background-position:  right bottom; }       This has worked!

Comment: After yet another google search and changing my <a class> tags to <div> tags in the nav bar brand I then added a <span> class and added some css to the span to specify background and text colours and font and this has worked. i also added this line   .navbar-nav {background: #F9F3DB; width:100%; margin-left: 17px;}  into my css to specify the nav bar colors. With a lot of fiddling and tweaking I've managed to finally get it to look how i want so I think I've pretty much solved this now.